# How to extract latitude and longitude from Google Maps autocomplete

Tags: google-maps, latitude-longitude

I'm building an web app that uses this code to search for addresses:

http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete.html

Type there, New York, NY.

So, when the map is loaded in the DOM after the user using the autocomplete option, the user can save the Location Address in the database, and it will be available as it is "ex. New York, NY". But, for the application I need to save also the Latitude and Longitude.

But I have no ideia how to grab them from the Google API.

As a test app, I'm still using the google code.
I guess I should create some HIDDEN fields and assign the latitude and longitude to them as the user chooses the Address.

Any implementation for my problem is welcome!!

Thanks in advance

**P.S:**
*As I'm new in StackOverflow I could't answer myself.
So I'm editing the post, as suggested by stackoverflow, and here is the solution based in Daniel's answer and some researches in the Google Api:*

```
function getLatLng( address ) 
{
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address' : address }, function( results, status ) {
        if ( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {
            var mapLatLng = document.getElementById( 'mapLatLng' ); // mapLatLng is my hidden field, use your own
            mapLatLng.value = results[0].geometry.location.lat() + ', ' + results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        } else {
            alert( "Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status );
        }

    });            
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Google API to get the Longitude and Latitude from your address.
As you already said, you should implement a hidden field where the result should be inserted.
Then you can save the location together with the coordinates.

I recently implemented this function in one of my projects:

```
function getLatLngFromAddress(city, country){

  var address = city +", "+ country;
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      $('#latitude').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
      $('#longitude').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());

    } else {
      console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Daniel is right for the most part, where he is incorrect is his access of the property here:

```
$('#latitude').val(results[0].geometry.location.Pa)
$('#longitude').val(results[0].geometry.location.Qa)
```

You should instead use the lat() and lng() functions provided:

```
$('#latitude').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat())
$('#longitude').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng())
```